# How to disable bluetooth device when startup on Ubuntu 12.4

Tags: boot

How to disable bluetooth device when startup on Ubuntu 12.4, I've accessed `/etc/init/bluetooth.conf` file and comment `#start on started dbus` line. But when PC bootup Bluetooth device still running.

How can I disable bluetooth device when system startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will disable bluetooth service on startup:

```
# bluez - bluetooth daemon

description     "bluetooth daemon"

#start on started dbus
stop on runlevel [0123456]
```

It seems that an error occured when you edited `bluetooth.conf` file. Do you comment `stop on stopping dbus`?

If you want to turn off bluetooth device, try remove it from kernel module load at startup. Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, add a line:

```
blacklist bluetooth
```

Comment: i've do follow your guide, but bluetooth device still running.

Comment: i've do follow your guide, bluetooth device stop when startup. The Icon bluetooth still appear beacause bluetooth_applet running. Thanks for Gnouc'answered

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following line:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 down
```

to `/etc/rc.local` before the `exit` command. You can edit the file using `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`.

Comment: I want to disable device before it startup.